# How to Label the "Outliers" in the box plot when there are many values which equals the outlier?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

[image: original box plot with 6 outliers]

Please refer the box plot picture above .I Want to label only the outliers.
I use the below code to make a label column to label the outlier.

```
outliers_price = boxplot(Ready_to_work_data$median_price ~ 
Ready_to_work_data$Regionname,plot=FALSE)$out
Ready_to_work_data$lable_price <- ifelse(Ready_to_work_data$median_price %in% 
outliers_price, Ready_to_work_data$median_price, "")
```

Now when I use the code geom_text(aes(label= lable_price)), I see the below plot (plot2) where all the matching values are highlighted many of which aren't outliers. How do I resolve this ?

[image: Plot2 with multiple lables]

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no data provided in the question, it's hard to reproduce the needed plot. But here is one solution for tagging the overlapping outliers with non-overlapping labels. The labels will not overlap when the points overlap because `ggstatsplot` uses `ggrepel` in the backdrop.

```r
library(ggstatsplot)

ggbetweenstats(
  data = movies_long,
  x = genre,
  y = rating,
  plot.type = "box",
  outlier.tagging = TRUE,
  outlier.label = title,
  outlier.coef = 2,
  messages = FALSE
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>